# Import js lib into Monaco Editor

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

How do I import a JavaScript API (like ProcessingJS) into Monaco so that intellisense and syntax hilighting will work?  I've looked through the API docs and as many examples as I can find, but have yet to find the answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Monaco intellisense works aout of the box and is awesome. Try this example:

https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#extending-language-services-configure-javascript-defaults

Modify it like the following so it starts validating there you will have autompletion and error diagnostics:

`// validation settings
monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.setDiagnosticsOptions({
    noSemanticValidation: false,
    noSyntaxValidation: false,
});`

. Also you could mix your js projects wiht typescript / jsdocs types declarations and will be better :